# How to automatically delete file older than 24 hours of a .pdf format in a specific folder with PHP

Tags: php, directory, file-manipulation

I keep getting many pdf file in my directory `root/files/pdfs`. I want a PHP script to automatically delete only the `.pdf` files from the `pdfs` folder that are older than 24 hours (`86400` seconds).

What permissions will the `.php` file require?
Where to put the file?
Should I have to run the PHP by visiting the link of the PHP file?

NOTE: I have a FTP access to a subdomain

Comment: It's probably easier to do this with a shell script and a cron job, depending on your server/os.

Comment: It's better to use cron job for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method, it checks the file creation time. Or use "filemtime" for file modified time.

```
$dir = "root/files/pdfs/";   //your folder location

foreach (glob($dir."*.pdf") as $file) { 
    if (filectime($file) < time() - 86400) { 
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```